# Tool to visualize the device tree file (dtb) used by the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, device-tree

I am looking for a tool which can graphically represent the hardware device tree used in linux kernel. I am trying to understand linux kernel for particular arm chipset. It would be a really useful tool to have.

Comment: Are you asking simply for a way to display the contents of a .dtb-file? If so, fdtdump is your friend.

Comment: I want something which takes the dts or dtsi files and shows them graphically.

Comment: fdtdump is exactly what I needed. `dtc -I dtb -O dts <filename>` might also serve the purpose. A GUI viewer is available here: https://github.com/dev-0x7C6/fdt-viewer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the **Component inspector** tool.

[image]

It is part of  **[QorIQ Configuration Suite](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=PE_QORIQ_SUITE)** which is a plugin for Eclipse.

Download **[here](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=PE_QORIQ_SUITE&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab)**.
(Requires registration. Free to download.)

---

Personally as i am on the cmd-line most of the time, and quite addicted to `vi`, i find its built-in code folding capabilities are somewhat sufficient as long as the **`dts`** is properly indented.

Setup hot-keys commands to fold/expand blocks of code in `vi`
by adding the following lines to `.vimrc` :

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> zfa}<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F6> zo<CR>
```

With the above setup, to fold a block/node, simply move the cursor onto any of its lines(except the title) and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>. To expand a folded block/node, move to the line with the folded title and hit <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Here is what a partially folded dts looks like in `vi`.
[image]

Comment: does the QorIQ work for any target cpu? Or is does no mater because it is only some sort of tree editor?

Comment: unfortunately QorIQ Configuration Suite is not available anymore, any alternative?

Comment: @sherpya I use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [DeviceTree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plorefice.devicetree) extension

Answer (score 37):

**`dtc -O dts`**

```
sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o a.dts a.dtb
```

gives a well indented textual representation of the device tree `a.dtb`, which is easy to understand with a text editor. Or dump it to stdout with:

```
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o - a.dtb
```

The source code for `dtc` is present in the kernel tree itself at [`scripts/dtc/dtc.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/scripts/dtc/dtc.c#L166)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, with the device tree of Raspberry Pi 2, found in the first partition of `2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie-qemu.img`.

For convenience I have in my `.bashrc`:

```
dtbs() ( dtc -I dtb -O dts -o - "$1" )
dtsb() ( dtc -I dts -O dtb -o - "$1" )
```

`dtc` can also extract the DTS from `/proc` of a live kernel as shown at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265890/is-it-possible-to-get-the-information-for-a-device-tree-using-sys-of-a-running

Answer (score 16):

On linux we can directly open dtb file by using **fdtdump**

```
fdtdump dtb_file.dtb > /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: Best for a fast inspection of the content

Answer (score 3):

There are few tools:

- visualize FDT/DTB/DTBO -> https://github.com/dev-0x7C6/fdt-viewer
- visualize DTS (dead) -> https://github.com/TheCodeArtist/dtv-demo
- visualize DTS (my fork) -> https://github.com/bmx666/dtv-demo

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

As many of you have figured out after reading this question, it appears that the Component Inspector Tool is no longer available.

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (free) provides an extension through the marketplace called [DeviceTree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plorefice.devicetree) which helps in navigating device tree files (**NOTE:** - `.dts`-only files are supported for now). It does not appear to be as good as the Component Inspector Tool but it does perform basic functions like highlighting and collapsing.

Comment: It does not support reading dtb files, like the question asked. Only dts files...