# How can a C application work on multiple cores with gem5?

Tags: c, gem5

I am new with gem5 simulator. I have a C application that i want to make it run faster. So the first thing I've done is to optimize it using several techniques like loop unrolling and SIMD. And the next step, i intend to make it work on **multiple cores** (**X86** and **ARM**) for that i must use the gem5 simulator.

The application is for Radix4 computing. For now I've succeeded to make it work on one core systems for **X86** and **ARM** but, now i want to make it work on 4, 16, ... cores X86 or ARM.

could someone give me some hints or show me the right way to do this?
Thank you

this is a global idea about the application

```
void init_twiddle(int N)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<TWIDDLE_LIMIT; i++)
  {
   /*Filling the twiddle table*/
  }
}

void init_LUT(int N)
{
  LUT_n2 = malloc((1+PMAX)*sizeof(int*));
  for (i=0; i <= PMAX; i++){
    for (j=0; j < n; j++)
    /*Calculate radix parametrs and put them in a table*/
  }
}

void bit_r4_reorder(float* x, float* y, int N)
{
/*Bit reordering after calculating the radix4*/
}

void radix4(float *x,float *y, int N)
{
/*function for the radix4 computing*/
}

int main()
{
/*Calling the previous functions*/ 
}
```

Comment: A bit broad, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and I'm sorry for that ... But i didn't even know how to make the question more clearer without revealing  my code

Comment: And why would revealing your code -- or a dumbed-down example -- be a problem?

Comment: I've added the code structure to have an idea about it...I hope that could help

Comment: Excuse me for being dense. But what kind of OS are we talking about here? Are you actually asking for "how to do threads", or is there more to the question that I don't see?

Comment: no OS; i will use gem5 in **SE** mode (Syscall Emulator mode) it does not need OS the only thing that the application must be linked statically

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528068/841108) to a very related question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application doesn't know that it's being run on a simulated system, so you can treat gem5 as a real system to achieve your goal. i.e., by using OpenMP or MPI.

If the system being modeled has these libraries (OpenMP or MPI) installed then these libraries should work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

On the gem5 side, you just need to:

- pass the `-n <number-of-cores>` option to the `fs.py` script
- for ARM, either:

  - use `--generate-dtb`. Recommended method. aarch64 blocked on: https://github.com/cirosantilli-work/gem5-issues/issues/18
  - select the correct dtb with the correct number of CPUs, e.g.:

    ```
    --dtb-file='system/arm/dt/armv7_gem5_v1_2cpu.dtb
    ```

    if you want 2 CPUs.

    If you need a CPU count that does not exist on any of the current dtbs, you could either:

    - convert the dtb to dts as explained at: [Tool to visualize the device tree file (dtb) used by the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000736/tool-to-visualize-the-device-tree-file-dtb-used-by-the-linux-kernel/39931834#39931834) modify them, and do the inverse
    - hack up the `Makefile` that generates the dtbs inside the gem5 tree: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/a66fe6a8c36c9ab49cb3a35065bfc645d51036c8/system/arm/dt/Makefile#L40 and regenerate them with:

      make -C system/arm/dt

    Further changes are needed if you want more than 8 cores in ARM: [How to run a gem5 arm aarch64 full system simulation with fs.py with more than 8 cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248067/how-to-run-a-gem5-arm-aarch64-full-system-simulation-with-fs-py-with-more-than-8/50248068#50248068)

  If you don't do this, the Linux kernel will not see all the CPUs in the system.

You can then verify that the number of cores changed with:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

As for your program itself, everything works just like for a real system, so you should look for tutorials on interfaces such as POSIX or C11 threads and then ask more specific problems if you encounter problems.