# Compile a C program with GCC, so that it can use all cpu cores in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a sample C program for addition. When I compile and run it with GCC it is using only one CPU core.

Is there any way to compile a C program so that it can use all CPU cores in Linux.

I used to compile like `gcc -O3 malloc.c`

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
        float *ptr;
        unsigned long long i;

        ptr = (float*) malloc(8000000000 * sizeof(float));

        for(i=0; i<8000000000; i++) {
                ptr[i] = i/10000;
        }

        clock_t tic = clock();

        for(i=0; i<8000000000; i++) {
                ptr[i] = (i/10000)+1.0;
        }

        clock_t toc = clock();

        printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use the make buildtool then you can use -j flag, where you can job simultaneously. For 4 cores you can give like `make -j4`, is that what your asking?

Comment: `<malloc.h>` is non standard and perhaps deprecated. Use `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: `make -j` is relevant at build time, not at run time

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I wasn't sure what OP asked for, that's why I just raised the question for clarification. If he wants to do this at runtime then I agree with you no point in using `make`.

Comment: I fit was as simple as flipping a switch, why wouldn't it be default on?

Comment: BTW, the `-O` switch is just for mentioning the level of optimization that you want.

Comment: @babon: but the OP dreams that `-O3` would parallelize his application, and that is not the case.

Comment: As `-O3` is for optimization, I am looking for any other options something like that for parallelization and I understood that there are none like that.

Comment: Please consider reading what @BasileStarynkevitch has said in the answer. Especially the part about "You won't be sure..."

Comment: @babon: Definitely

Comment: Note that `clock` does not give you elapsed "wall-clock" time, but used processor time, so (assuming the work could be split over several cores without any overhead) your program would print the same time for a single-threaded and for a multi-threaded version of the program.

Answer (score 16):

> Is there any way to compile a C program so that it can use all CPU cores in Linux.

**No**, not as magically as you want it to happen. [Parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization) of programs is a very difficult subject and in general cannot be done automagically. BTW, parallel programs might not be as efficient as you wish them to be (be aware of [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).

However, you could *design* and *code* a parallel program. You might for example use [posix threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). Beware, it is tricky! Read first some [*Pthread tutorial*](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). You won't be sure that all [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) would be used (since they are managed by the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))), but that is in practice very likely. Read also about [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

You could also use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC). You could code some of your numerical kernels using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). You could have a [multi-processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing) approach (e.g. forking several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), using [inter-process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)), perhaps using [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). Look also into the [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) approach, the [0mq](http://zeromq.org/) library (and many others).

You could read something on OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). You could also read something on Linux system programming, e.g. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) (or some newer book). See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Be aware that **designing, coding and debugging a [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)** (or concurrent, or [distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)) **application is *very* difficult**. Take into account the cost of development time (and the time, probably [*years*](http://norvig.com/21-days.html), needed to acquire the relevant skills). There is [No Silver Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)!

<sup>(it is not very realistic to transform an existing real-life sequential application into a parallel one; you usually have to design a parallel program from scratch)</sup>

Comment: Does `-ftree-parallelize-loops=4` still work in gcc?  If so, it might work here in this simple case with compile-time-constant large trip-counts for the loops.

Comment: Probably yes, but you should try (and the answer could be compiler version specific)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following pragma right above your `for` loops:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0; i<8000000000; i++) {
    ptr[i] = i/10000;
}
```

And add the `-fopenmp` option to your build options when you call gcc. By default, OpenMP will create as many threads as cores in your machine and will share workload evenly between them.

You can check this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) for more information on OpenMP.

Comment: Good! This changed the time of the second `for` loop from 8.48 seconds to 1.48 seconds. That is 5.7 times faster, which is what one might expect on my i7 cpu with 6 cores.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create several threads. Otherwise there is only one thread, and it runs on a single core (at a time).

Look at a tutorial about threads, specifically **pthreads**, to find out how to work with threads. Or you could use the **fork** system call to split your program into several processes, with one thread each.

Comment: It could be a multi-process program, not a multi-threaded one

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: True.

Comment: Creating several threads or processes is (relatively) easy. What's hard is how to partition the work so that they are actually able to proceed independently, but coordinate when they need to.

Comment: I don't think that synchronization and communication between threads or processes  is easy. My opinion is that it is *hard*.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I think everyone agrees with you. What I think triplee means is that calling pthread_create is easy. It is all the rest that is hard.

Comment: But `pthread_create` is not enough, even for the simplistic code given in the question!

Comment: AFAIK, creating multiple threads / process is not a guarantee that they will use multiple cores. Am I wrong?

Comment: @babon: you don't have any guarantee (and you probably don't want one). In practice and in most cases, several cores would be used. Read also about [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks. But, I guess this is exactly what the OP wants to achieve IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

You can create `n` ( n is number of cores assume) threads in your program and then you can set `CPU` affinity of each thread so that it is tied to particular `CPU Core`. `sched_setaffinity` or `pthread_setaffinity_np` is the one allows you to set `CPU` affinity.