# Running C extension in Python faster than plain C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have implemented a Python extension in C and found that executing a C function inside of Python to be 2x faster than just executing the C code from a C main.

But why is this faster? I would expect the plain C to be exactly the same performance when called from Python as it is when called from C.

Here is my experiment:

- Plain C compute code (simple 3for matrix-matrix multiplication)
- Plain C main function that calls the **mmult()** function
- Python extension wrapper to call the **mmult()** function
- All timing is happening entirely within the C code

***Here are my results:***

Pure C - 85us

Python Extension - 36us

---

Heres my code:

---

--mmult.cpp----------

```
#include "mmult.h"

void mmult(int32_t a[1024],int32_t b[1024],int32_t c[1024]) {

  struct timeval t1, t2;
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

  for(int i=0; i<32; i=i+1) {
    for(int j=0; j<32; j=j+1) {
        int32_t result=0;
         for(int k=0; k<32; k=k+1) {
           result+=a[i*32+k]*b[k*32+j];
         }
         c[i*32+j] = result;
      }
  }

  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

  double elapsedTime = (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) + (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000000;
  printf("elapsed time: %fus\n",elapsedTime);

}
```

--mmult.h-------

```
#include <stdint.h>

void mmult(int32_t a[1024],int32_t b[1024],int32_t c[1024]);
```

--main.cpp------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "mmult.h"

int main() {
  int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);
  int* b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);
  int* c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);

  for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    a[i]=i+1;
    b[i]=i+1;
    c[i]=0;
  }

  struct timeval t1, t2;
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  mmult(a,b,c);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

  double elapsedTime = (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) + (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000000;
  printf("elapsed time: %fus\n",elapsedTime);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);

  return 0;
}
```

Heres how I compile main:

```
gcc -o main main.cpp mmult.cpp -O3
```

---

--wrapper.cpp-----

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "mmult.h"

static PyObject* mmult_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
   int32_t* a;
   PyArrayObject* a_obj = NULL;
   int32_t* b;
   PyArrayObject* b_obj = NULL;
   int32_t* c;
   PyArrayObject* c_obj = NULL;

   int res = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO", &a_obj, &b_obj, &c_obj);

   if (!res)
      return NULL;

   a = (int32_t*) PyArray_DATA(a_obj);
   b = (int32_t*) PyArray_DATA(b_obj);
   c = (int32_t*) PyArray_DATA(c_obj);

   /* call function */
   mmult(a,b,c);

   Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

/*  define functions in module */
static PyMethodDef TheMethods[] = {
   {"mmult_wrapper", mmult_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "your c function"},
   {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef cModPyDem = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
   "mmult", "Some documentation",
   -1,
   TheMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_c_module(void) {
   PyObject* retval = PyModule_Create(&cModPyDem);
   import_array();
   return retval;
}
```

--setup.py-----

```
import os
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
cur = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
c_module = Extension("c_module", sources=["wrapper.cpp","mmult.cpp"],include_dirs=[cur,numpy.get_include()])
setup(ext_modules=[c_module])
```

--code.py-----

```
import c_module
import time
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.ndarray((32,32),dtype='int32',buffer=np.linspace(1,1024,1024,dtype='int32').reshape(32,32))
    b = np.ndarray((32,32),dtype='int32',buffer=np.linspace(1,1024,1024,dtype='int32').reshape(32,32))
    c = np.ndarray((32,32),dtype='int32',buffer=np.zeros((32,32),dtype='int32'))

    c_module.mmult_wrapper(a,b,c)
```

Heres how I compile the Python extension:

```
python3.6 setup_sw.py build_ext --inplace
```

---

**UPDATE**

Ive updated the mmult.cpp code to run the 3for for 1,000,000 iterations internally. This resulted in very similar times:

Pure C - 27us

Python Extension - 27us

Comment: You're using two different compilers, correct? So I'm guessing that one is better at creating efficient executables in this one instance

Comment: _executing a C function inside of Python to be 2x faster than just executing the C code from a C main_ <--- are you sure, how do you benchmarking the speed here, I'm curious to know what made you to come in conclusion that executing  C function in Python is faster?

Comment: In most of these cases, the answer is incorrect benchmarking.

Comment: `int* a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);` -- This number of entries (to me) is a tiny amount to be used for meaningful benchmark tests.

Answer (score 7):

85 microseconds is too small a delay to be measured reliably and repeatedly. For example, [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) effects (or [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), or [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)) may dominate the computation time (and alter it to make that timing meaningless).

<sup>(I guess you are on Linux/x86-64)</sup>

As a rule of thumb, try to have a run lasting about half a second at least, and repeat the benchmarking a few times. You could also use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) for measurements.

See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). There are *several* notions of time (elapsed "real" time, monotonic time, process cpu time, thread cpu time, etc...). You could consider using [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) or [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) to measure time.

BTW, you might compile with a more recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (in November 2017, [GCC7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) and in a few weeks GCC8) and you want to compile with `gcc -march=native -O3` for benchmarking purposes. Try also other [optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and tuning. You could also try another compiler, e.g. [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/).

Look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528068/841108) answer (regarding parallelization) to a relevant question. Probably the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package is using (internally) similar techniques (outside of the [Python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), so could be faster than your naive sequential matrix multiplication code in C.