# How to run a gem5 arm aarch64 full system simulation with fs.py with more than 8 cores?

Tags: gem5

If I try to use more than `--num-cpus=8` cores, e.g. 16, 32 or 64, the terminal just stays blank.

Tested with gem5 at commit 2a9573f5942b5416fb0570cf5cb6cdecba733392 and Linux kernel 4.16.

Related thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15469.html

Answer (score 2):

If I add more to Ciro's answer, the current GICv2 model in gem5 supports single core  by default because of [this line of code](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/src/dev/arm/gic_v2.cc#787). Without enabling `gem5ExtensionsEnabled`, it won't update the `highest_int` with the receiving interrupt number, and as a result the received interrupt won't get posted to a specified cpu to invoke a handler. That is, there is no jump to interrupt handler. In addition, even when we turn on `gem5ExtensionsEnabled`, I think that it will support up to 4 cores because the default values of `INT_BITS_MAX` and `itLines` are 32 and 128, respectively (see [this](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/src/dev/arm/gic_v2.cc#775)); it checks 32 interrupt lines per core across 4 cores. For example, imagine that a system features 16 cores and cpu 5 executes the loop. Also, suppose that the other core (say core 11) already has an interrupt with higher priority than this. Then, the loop will ignore the other interrupt from core 11 because the loop index `x` can grow at most to 3.

To turn on `gem5ExtensionsEnabled`, you can pass an option `--param='system.realview.gic.gem5_extensions=True'` to your command as Ciro stated. However, note that the parameter is used to set `haveGem5Extensions` variable at [here](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/src/dev/arm/gic_v2.cc#72), not setting `gem5ExtensionsEnabled`, which is enabled only when a firmware code writes some data (0x200) to GIC distributor register at GICD_TYPER offset (see [this](https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/src/dev/arm/gic_v2.cc#538)).

Answer (score 1):

**Newer method: GICv3**

Since GICv3 was implemented in February 2019 at https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/13436 you can just use it instead.

The GICv3 hardware natively supports more than 8 CPUs, so it just works.

As of July 2020 gem5 3ca404da175a66e0b958165ad75eb5f54cb5e772, GICv3 is the default GIC for the `VExpress_GEM5_V2` but the default fs.py machine is `VExpress_GEM5_V2` at that commit, so you just have to select it with:

```
fs.py --machine-type VExpress_GEM5_V2
```

Once I did that, it just worked, Atomic boot took about 6x on 16 cores compared to a single CPU. Tested with this setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d0ada7f58c6624662bbfa3446c7c26422d1c5afb#gem5-arm-full-system-with-more-than-8-cores

**Older method: GICv2 extensions**

As mentioned at: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg24593.html gem5 has a GICv2 extension + kernel patch that allows this:

- use the ARM linux kernel fork from: https://gem5.googlesource.com/arm/linux/+/refs/heads/gem5/v4.15 in particular the GICv2 extension script commit
- for `fs.py` add the options `--param 'system.realview.gic.gem5_extensions = True' --generate-dtb`

Tested with this setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/bab029f60656913b5dea629a220ae593cc16147d#gem5-arm-full-system-with-more-than-8-cores (gem5 4c8efdbef45d98109769cf675ee3411393e8ed06, Linux kernel fork v4.15, aarch64).