# How to run gem5 on KVM on ARM with multiple cores?

Tags: gem5

Single core worked with fs.py at a5bc2291391b0497fdc60fdc960e07bcecebfb8f (Nov 2018), but multicore hanged in early in the boot process. Is multicore KVM supported on ARM or not?

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2019, gem5's ARM KVM is generally not robust enough to be generally recommended.

Multicore works on some setups and fails on others, so there are likely outstanding bugs, although I haven't seen a clear investigation that pinpointed those bugs yet.

There are also issues with GICv2 vs GICv3 version incompatibilities: only GICv2 hosts were supported natively at that point, although the option was added to use an emulated gem5 GICv2 with KVM https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/30921

It is likely not extremely hard to get it working, but it does require someone to sit down and focus on it for a few weeks.

Related threads:

- https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-694 for more than 8 cores, make sure to enable the GICv2 gem5 extensions if you are using the gem5 GICv2 emulation as mentioned: [How to run a gem5 arm aarch64 full system simulation with fs.py with more than 8 cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248067/how-to-run-a-gem5-arm-aarch64-full-system-simulation-with-fs-py-with-more-than-8/50248068#50248068)