# Measuring the impact on performance of assembly on gem5

Tags: gem5

I'm trying to measure the impact on performance caused by replacing a script's C code with assembly on key sections of it, and the resulting execution time is about 40% of the original when ran from a `TimingSimpleCPU` on SE mode.

So I'm wondering if this change is to be expected, or if it could be caused by the CPU choice or some other factor such as the compiler's optimization level.

I know the question is a bit broad, but i just need a general idea of where to start looking for an explanation.

Comment: Without more details, it is impossible to say. Look into the `--debug-flags ExecAll` logs to see if they match your system of interest (extremelly unlikely, since `TimingSimpleCPU` has no pipeline and therefore does not correspond to any real hardware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554232/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gem5-cpu-models-and-which-one-is-more-accurat/58554233#58554233 )