# Why does gem5 run parsec3.0 encounter deadlock error？

Tags: linux, benchmarking, gem5

I run gem5 full system mode on a multi-core system, use AtomicCPU to establish a checkpoint, and then turn to O3CPU to start, and execute a command similar to the following:

`./build/ARM_MOESI_hammer/gem5.opt -d fs_results/blackscholes configs/example/fs.py --ruby  --num-cpus=64 --caches --l2cache  --cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU  --network=garnet2.0 --disk-image=$M5_PATH/disks/expanded-linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/GEM5/gem5/2017sys/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 --param 'system.realview.gic.gem5_extensions = True'`

Next, establish a checkpoint, and use the following command to restore the checkpoint and run PARSEC.

`./build/ARM_MOESI_hammer/gem5.opt -d fs_results/blackscholes configs/example/fs.py --ruby  --num-cpus=64 --caches --l2cache  --cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU   --network=garnet2.0 --disk-image=$M5_PATH/disks/expanded-linaro-minimal-aarch64.img --kernel=/home/GEM5/gem5/2017sys/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64.20170616 --param 'system.realview.gic.gem5_extensions = True'  --restore-with-cpu=DeriveO3CPU --script=../arm-gem5-rsk/parsec_rcs/blackscholes_simsmall_64.rcS -r 1`

But I encountered the following problems：

First of all, the `rcs` file is not executed. Does the startup checkpoint conflict with the `--script` command?

The second point, I manually enter in the operating system booted by gem5：

`parsecmgmt -a run -c gcc-hooks -i simsmall -n 1 -p blackscholes`
I got the following error：

```
panic: Possible Deadlock detected. Aborting!
```

I tried to find the solution from the internet，it seems that there used to be a way to add parameters`--garnet-network=flexible`，but this method is no longer applicable in gem5-20.0 version.

Can someone help me solve this deadlock problem? By the way, when running the facesim program, I can get the correct running result by using 'test' input.

Comment: checkpoint: works fine with `--script` when I last checked. Here is [a setup with some explanations](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-restore-new-script), make sure that you understand well how those things work. About: `panic: Possible Deadlock detected. Aborting`, guest failures are extremely hard to diagnoze without a more narrowed down cause. Sometimes it is easy, sometimes hard to reach such cause. Give it a try by looking at `ExecAll` logs, and comparing to the program disassembly, to see if you find a minimal non correct step.